# Joomla 3.7 not installing Error displaying the error page

Tags: php, mysql, joomla, joomla3.7

I have downloaded Joomla 3.7, and trying to setup on Fresh Ubuntu 16.04 server with LAMP Stack, getting the error:

> Error displaying the error page

My environment is  apache 2.4, MySQL 5.7.18, PHP 7.0.15.

I have searched a lot over internet but I am getting this error before setting up Joomla site.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6FKu.png)

Answer (score 2):

I had this same error updating a client's site and the cause was that it was an older site and in the database settings it was still using MySQL, as opposed to MySQLi.

From **Global Configuration > Server Tab > Database settings** I changed  the database type to MySQLi and all was good.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Run `apt-get install php7.0-xml` solved the problem for me

Comment: Everyone should vote to reopen this question so that this helpful comment can be posted as a solo answer.

Comment: this is also what worked for me: `apt-get install php7.0-xml`, thanks @user2196728

Comment: This ```apt-get install php7.0-xml``` worked for me too. Cheers